# How to check whether transaction is successful and print the transaction signature in Solana Pay using Web3.js?

Tags: solana-web3js

I have integrated the Solana Pay using Web3.js. I am getting the transaction signature as well. But I want to check whether the transaction is successful or not. I am using solana/web3.js v1.41.3.

Here is the code below:

```
                const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);
                await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
                console.log(connection);
```

The above code is working well but I want to check the transaction successful or not. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getSignatureStatus` of the `connection` object e.g

```js
const getConfirmation = async (connection: Connection, tx: string) => {
  const result = await connection.getSignatureStatus(tx, {
    searchTransactionHistory: true,
  });
  return result.value?.confirmationStatus;
};
```